# solving system of non linear equations with symbols in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I'm having trouble solving a non-linear system of equations for three unknowns when they all equal zero. Below is the system of equations:

```
[thrust + (1372026816786920195775*conj(alpha))/72057594037927936 - (1376539794479570331075*conj(del_e))/4611686018427387904 - 20500*sin(alpha) + (1122106572074213962575*conj(alpha)^2)/18014398509481984 - (362715984096719412825*conj(alpha)^3)/4503599627370496 - (932450120730943022325*conj(del_e)^2)/36028797018963968 - (1323468681345438265575*conj(alpha)*conj(del_e))/72057594037927936 - 249646238091286443225/144115188075855872, ...
(1694368907620451361981*conj(alpha))/36028797018963968 - (5464341926515415557545*conj(del_e))/9007199254740992 + (12099358590756091969971*conj(del_e)^2)/144115188075855872 + (5797489749151212889611*conj(del_e)^3)/9007199254740992 + (1920581437875437136969*conj(alpha)*conj(del_e)^2)/4503599627370496 + (9122289677511805302255*conj(alpha)^2*conj(del_e))/18014398509481984 - (11724978367343653317573*conj(alpha)*conj(del_e))/144115188075855872 - 11804235259178435103489/576460752303423488, ...
20500*cos(alpha) - (15524187*del_e)/400 + (178275*(beta^2 - 1)*((4741579964779915*conj(alpha))/1125899906842624 - (5376382598456109*conj(alpha)^2)/1125899906842624 + (41049*conj(alpha)^3)/4000 - (1182161547400015*conj(alpha)^4)/140737488355328 + 2482884914885181/18014398509481984))/2]
```

I'm solving for `thrust`, `del_e`, and `alpha`.

I attempted using `fsolve`, but that failed due to symbols any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `fsolve` is a numeric method so it's pretty clear this won't work for Symbolic Math. Have you tried `solve`? You likely won't be able to solve this numerically given that you have a free symbolic variable `beta`.

Comment: I'm assuming your symbolic parameters are all real-valued (not complex). By default, Matlab's `syms` creates complex-valued variable. This is likely why you see `conj` in your expressions. I suggest `syms thrust del_e alpha beta real;` to specify these as real-valued.